# When should I use delete? (Consequences of not deleting after a dynamically created 2d array)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, delete-operator

I am new to dynamic allocation and pointers. I will try to fill out a 2D dynamic array from a file and then apply a maze-solving algorithm (wall follower)on it.

Assuming I create a dynamically allocated 2D array like this:

```
int** board;
board = new int* [rowsize];

for(int row = 0; row < rowsize; row++)
{
  board[row] = new int[colsize];
}
```

If I know that I won't be using this pointer for another variable, can I get away with not using delete for `board` ? If not what could potentially go wrong (If you are familiar with the wall follower algorithm) ? Also how do I delete a pointer to a pointer, would `delete board`  be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I get away with not using delete for `board`?

Yes, but not for very long: repeated failure to delete arrays that your program allocates is a memory leak that eventually runs your process out of memory.

> how do I delete a pointer to a pointer, would `delete board` be sufficient?

No, you will need to delete each pointer that you allocated and stored inside `board`:

```
for(int row = 0; row < rowsize; row++) {
    delete[] board[row];
}
delete[] board;
```

Note square brackets after `delete` to indicate that you deleting an array, they are very important.

Allocating an deallocating memory for a rectangular matrix is a solved problem in C++ library. Switch to using a vector of vectors to avoid dynamic resource allocations:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> board(rowsize, std::vector<int>(colsize, 0));
```

Comment: Here is what I don't get. Assuming I only use the program just for one purpose. Meaning: Read the data from file, go through the maze, print out the path, then quit. How is it that there is still a memory leak? I thought memory leak referred to when you use the pointer to point to another location, and now the previous location is inaccessible. In a simple program like this I am having a hard time visualizing the 'leaked' memory.

Comment: @LucAux Memory leak happens when your calls to `new` and `delete` are our of balance. When your program quits, OS cleans up "the mess" after your program, including memory leaks, unclosed file descriptors, and so on. However, it is a good idea to clean them out yourself, in case you want to run your code through a memory profiler, or someone else copies your code to run it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't delete the arrays you allocated they will continue to consume memory until the program is terminated. This might not technically be wrong, but it is wasteful.

With regard to deleting the `board` - no, it is not enough. You should delete every pointer you allocate with `new`:

```
for(int row = 0; row < rowsize; row++)
{
    delete[] board[row];
}
delete[] board;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to `delete` is the memory you **allocated** with **new**. That means that you don't deallocate the pointer itself, but the heap's memory it is pointing at.

So, you only need to do `delete[] board`. This will free up the `int*` array. It is not strictly necessary to use `[]` in this case, since it is a fundamental type array, but it is good practice to use it always for arrays, so you won't mess up when it's not like that.

Calling `delete[]` on an array will call the destructors of all objects inside the array itself, as well as freeing up the array. It is not necessary however for fundamental types.

Also note that you don't need to free the  `int** board`. The pointer are variables like any other with some special capability, but they are allocated in the stack just like any other when you declare them like that.

Hope it helps :)